# java многопоточность HttpsUrlConnection Proxy

Tags: java, многопоточность, proxy, прокси, httpsurlconnection

существует некий метод:

```
public static String get(String urlString, String proxyIp, int port)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyIp, port));
        HttpsURLConnection uc;
        uc = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result.append(line);
            result.append("\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

который вполне стабильно работает с различными прокси.

существует мультипоточная система, которая дергает этот метод из разных потоков подставляя свои прокси.

существует задача, получить страницу для определённого региона, для чего прокси и используется.
веселье начинается, когда разные потоки пытаются подключится к разным проксям. в итоге получается дичайшая мешанина с регионами. для примера: поток с корейским прокси получает страницу для бразильского региона, потому что параллелый поток с бразильским прокси также пытается получить страницу.

Прошу помочь найти решение этой проблемы, или хотя бы ссылку на ресурс или API

PS
Пробовал Apache HTTP client, но там начинаются проблемы с SSL трафиком через HTTP прокси

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272681/httpurlconnection-thread-safety

Comment: Мне кажется у вас проблема, где то в другом месте. В этом методе, если я не ошибаюсь, не должно возникнуть ошибок, т.к. все переменные в нем локальные и не используется какое то состояние.